# Socket.io with two node.js servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am a confused how to use socket.io so that two node servers can emit events between each other.

**Server.js localhost:9200**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('messageFromClient', function(data) {
        socket.broadcast.to(data.chatRoom).emit('messageFromServer', data);
    });

});
```

This socket connection listens to the server like so

```
var appPort  = 9200; 

var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var http     = require('http');
var server   = http.createServer(app);
var io       = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Launch server
server.listen(appPort);
```

---

**I have a website being served by node.js... Server.js localhost:3000**: I need this to be able to receive and emit events from **localhost:9200**

How do I setup server.js for **localhost:3000**?

Comment: I am confused, because I was told to setup a redis server, but that seems overkill and I don't really understand what that entails. I keep coming across https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client and I think that might be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, it's really quite simple. There can be two node servers, but only one server needs to use socket.io and handle the events. All you need to do to connect is share the client side script via CORS, I wanted to avoid CORS, but you only need to share the socket.io script over CORS and nothing else, so it's not so bad.

First thing needed is to allow your other domain to access the script via CORS.

```
// requires cors module I think (var cors = require('cors');)
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3100',
  credentials: true
};
```

Then secondly, it's important client side to use `io.connect` I am not sure if that was depreciated or something but none of the modern docs mention this.

```
// What worked for me
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3100');

// Docs say
var socket = io('http://localhost:3100'); // ?? I am not sure why but io.connect worked for me.
```